# Как получить содержимое блока страницы WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница, в ней есть таблица, как получить таблицу с этой страницы?

do_shortcode('[table]') не работает.

Comment: Покажите шорткод в контенте страницы и ваш код.

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня на странице дефолтный блок с типом "таблица", я пытался обратиться к нему через шорткод [table] - не работает